How can I delete a "." from a list in Common Lisp?
I'm new on lisp and I'm finding a difficulty while working with "append". I have to reorder a list and put the first element of the input list as the last of the output list. I've trying with "append" and "nconc", and any time I get the list I want, but with a "." before the last element. What this dot means? Is there any way to avoid this symbol to appear?
Thanks a lot!
 (nconc (rest l) (first l)) >> (B C D E . A)

 (append (rest l) (first l)) >> (B C D E . A)


The . means it isn't a "real" list, which should end with a nil.

At the most basic level, lists are created with a series of cons calls:
(cons 1       2     )  ; (1 . 2)
(cons 1 (cons 2 NIL))  ; (1 2 . NIL)  = (1 2)

(cons 1 (cons 2       3     ))  ; (1 2 . 3)
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 NIL)))  ; (1 2 3 . NIL) = (1 2 3) 

NIL is the special marker to signal the end of a list. Hence, the NIL after the . can just disappear together with the .. But with any other atom after the ., it can't.
append is a higher-level function, which appends two lists:
; l = (1 2 3)
(append (rest l) (first l))
=
(cons 2 (cons 3   1))
=
(     2       3 . 1)

This is so because first l element here is not a list.(*) But we can make a list out of it:
; l = (1 2 3)
(append (rest l) (list (first l)))
=
(cons 2 (cons 3  (list 1)))
=
(cons 2 (cons 3  (cons 1   NIL)))
=
(     2       3        1 . NIL  )
=
(     2       3        1        )

nconc in this respect is just like append.

(*)  nor is it NIL in which case it will get treated as the end of list marker, and disappear together with the dot. Which shows  that NIL is an empty list, too:
; l = (NIL 2 3)
(append (rest l) (first l))
=
(cons 2 (cons 3   NIL))
=
(     2       3 . NIL )
=
(     2       3       )

; l = ((0 1) 2 3)
(append (rest l) (first l))
=
(cons 2 (cons 3  (list 0 1)))
=
(     2       3  .    (0 1) )
=
(     2       3        0 1  )


It worked!  Thanks a lot!
